# SwiftUI: Commands on macOS for multiple windows

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to add individual commands to each window of my app (see simplified code example below). Although the `.commands` modifiers are used separately on both Windows, all commands are always available.

Is there a native SwiftUI way to make the first/second commands only show up on the first/second window respectively? Or at least be enabled/disabled?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct CommandsTestProjectApp: App {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow

    var body: some Scene {
        // FIRST WINDOW
        Window("First Window", id: "FirstWindow") {
            Text("First Window")
            Button("Open Second Window") {
                openWindow.callAsFunction(id: "SecondWindow")
            }
        }
        .commands {
            FirstCommands()
        }

        // SECOND WINDOW
        Window("Second Window", id: "SecondWindow") {
            Text("Second Window")
        }
        .commands {
            SecondCommands()
        }
    }
}

struct FirstCommands: Commands {
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
            Button("First button") {

            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondCommands: Commands {
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
            Button("Second button") {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]